# Hello can anyone help me i m new to webscraping i m scraping stackoverflow website but i got stuck not able to get user-tags

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to scrape user tags (programming languages) from a page
def scrape_user_tags(page_url):
    response = requests.get(page_url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

    user_tags = []

    # Find the div with the specific class
    user_tags_div = soup.find('div', class_='user-tags')

    if user_tags_div:
        # Find all 'a' tags inside the div and split them by ","
        tags = user_tags_div.find_all('a', href=True)
        user_tags = [tag.text.strip() for tag in tags]

    return user_tags

# Specify the URL of the page you want to scrape
page_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all'

print(f"Scraping user tags from the specified page...\n")

user_tags = scrape_user_tags(page_url)

if user_tags:
    print("User Tags (Programming Languages):")
    for tag in user_tags:
        print(tag)
else:
    print("No user tags found on this page.")

print('\nScraping completed.')
```

I need each user profile user-tags such as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b),[java](/questions/tagged/java),[python](/questions/tagged/python) etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to print user names + their tags (also, don't forget to set `User-Agent` http header to get correct response from the server):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0"
}

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")


for user in soup.select("div:has(>.user-tags)"):
    name = user.select_one(".user-details a").text
    tags = ", ".join(a.text for a in user.select(".user-tags a"))
    print(f"{name:<30} {tags}")
```

Prints:

```
Jon Skeet                      c#, java, .net
VonC                           git, github, eclipse
Gordon Linoff                  sql, sql-server, mysql
BalusC                         java, jsf, jsf-2
Martijn Pieters                python, python-3.x, python-2.7
T.J. Crowder                   javascript, jquery, arrays
Marc Gravell                   c#, .net, linq
Darin Dimitrov                 c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3
CommonsWare                    android, java, android-intent
Greg Hewgill                   git, python, version-control
Hans Passant                   c#, .net, winforms
Quentin                        javascript, html, css
akrun                          r, dplyr, dataframe
SLaks                          c#, javascript, .net
Alex Martelli                  python, list, multidimensional-array
paxdiablo                      c, c++, bash
unutbu                         python, pandas, numpy
jezrael                        pandas, python, dataframe
Mark Byers                     python, c#, mysql
Christian C. Salvadó           javascript, jquery, html
Felix Kling                    javascript, asynchronous, ajax
Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams         python, string, bash
anubhava                       regex, bash, shell
CB Bailey                      git, c++, gitignore
Barmar                         javascript, php, mysql
JaredPar                       c#, .net, c++
marc_s                         sql-server, sql, c#
Jonathan Leffler               c, bash, c++
Sergey Kalinichenko            c#, java, c++
BoltClock                      css, css-selectors, html
Stephen C                      java, class, multithreading
Guffa                          c#, javascript, jquery
jfriend00                      javascript, node.js, jquery
JB Nizet                       java, hibernate, spring
Eric Lippert                   c#, .net, c++
Gumbo                          php, javascript, json
```